# powershell script to find a process running by a user, if not send an email

Tags: powershell

Very new at PowerShell. I have to write a script that

> 1. will find out the VM's first based on a naming scheme, and then
> 2. query each VM to find if any PowerShell process is running under a
>    specific user, say "userA", if it can not find the process on any VM
>    then
> 3. it will compile a list of the VM that does not have the process
>    running and then send that in an email.

I have the 1st part figured out, however, I'm having difficulty with the 2nd part. The below code always returns "process not running" when I know its running on a VM. I think the problem is there is more than one PowerShell process. can someone please guide me?

```
$process = Invoke-Command -ComputerName "vmonnetwork" -ScriptBlock { Get-Process -name "powershell" -IncludeUserName } | Select-Object UserName

if ($process -eq "userA") {
    Write-Host "Process is running"
}
else {
    Write-host "Process is not running"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these changes to your code (not both):

Change `if ($process -eq "userA")` to `if ($process.UserName -eq "userA")`

*or*

Change `Select-Object UserName` to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName`

Comment: Thanks @boxdog, none of the above worked. but I was able to get it working with the below change - if (($process) -cmatch "username"). thanks for your help.

Comment: The likely reason my suggestions didn't work is that `UserName` contains the domain as well as the name (e.g. `domain\user`), but you are supplying just the name, which, of course, fails an equality check.  The `-match` operator is performing a regex comparison, so it can find the name substring within the longer string.  I'd be careful of getting into the habit of using `-match` as an equivalent to `-eq` as you can get unintended matching that is difficult to debug.